# Apache Flink table-walkthrough missing dependency?

Tags: apache-flink

I am following the steps from the [documentation](https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-release-1.15/docs/try-flink/table_api/). When running `mvn install` for the [table-walkthrough](https://github.com/apache/flink-playgrounds/tree/master/table-walkthrough) project I am getting however the error below:

```
org.apache.flink.table.api.ValidationException: Could not find any factories that implement 'org.apache.flink.table.delegation.ExecutorFactory' in the classpath.

at org.apache.flink.table.factories.FactoryUtil.discoverFactory(FactoryUtil.java:387)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.create(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:295)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.internal.TableEnvironmentImpl.create(TableEnvironmentImpl.java:266)
at org.apache.flink.table.api.TableEnvironment.create(TableEnvironment.java:95)
at org.apache.flink.playgrounds.spendreport.SpendReportTest.testReport(SpendReportTest.java:52)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After manually adding this dependency, I am able to run the code and update the `SpendReport#report` method as requested.

```xml
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
            <artifactId>flink-table-planner_${scala.binary.version}</artifactId>
            <version>${flink.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

I believe this dependency needs to be added in the sample project (IDE or mvn command, both are failing without it).